# Read data from huge Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

Scenario:
Collection A has 40 million records and each record has almost 20 fields.
Get 5 (defined)fields from A and change the field name and populate in collection B.

Example:

**A**
"_id" is the primary key here

```
{
"_id":123
"id":123
"title":"test"
"summary": "test"
"version":1
"parentid":12
}
```

**B**

```
{
"_id":123
"p$id":123
"p$parentid":12
"p$title":"test"
}
```

Can someone please suggest a good way to write a code for this scenario?

I wrote the code but it took 5 hrs to complete.
My Code:

### config.py:

It has all Mongo DB related details.

### Actual code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import  operator
import datetime

print "Start time", datetime.datetime.now()

primary_dict = {}
primary_list = []
secondary_dict = {}
secondary_list = []
missing_id = []
mismatch_id = []

alias_dict = {
            "_id": "_id",
             "id":"p$id"
            "title": "p$title"
             "parentid":"p$parentid"
        }

def mongo_connect(host, port, db, collection):
    client = MongoClient(host, port)
    db_obj = client[db]
    collection_obj = db_obj[collection]
    return collection_obj

def primary():

    global primary_list
    global primary_dict
    global secondary_dict
    global secondary_list
    global missing_id

    primary_collection = mongo_connect(config.mongo_host, config.mongo_port, config.mongo_primary_db, config.mongo_primary_collection)
    secondary_collection = mongo_connect(config.mongo_host, config.mongo_port, config.mongo_secondary_db, config.mongo_secondary_collection)

    for dict1 in primary_collection.find({},{"_id":1,"title":1}).batch_size(1000):
        count = 0
        target_id = ''
        primary_list = []
        secondary_list = []
        target_id = dict1['_id']

        primary_list.insert(count, dict1)
        if (secondary_collection.find_one({"_id":target_id})) is None:
            missing_id.append(target_id)
            continue
        else:
            secondary_list.insert(count,secondary_collection.find_one({"_id":target_id}))

        compare(primary_list, secondary_list)


def compare(list1, list2):

    global  alias_dict
    global mismatch_id
    global missing_id
    for l1, l2 in zip(primary_list,secondary_list):
        if len(l1) != len(l2):
            mismatch_id.append(l1['_id'])
            continue
        else:
            for key, value in l1.items():
                if value != l2[alias_dict[key]]:
                    mismatch_id.append(l1['_id'])


primary()

print "Mismatch id list", mismatch_id

print "Missing Id list", missing_id

print "End time", datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code you used to do this?

Comment: Do you have an _id Key (primary Key) in your Collection?

Comment: I have posed my code and "_id" is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do this:

```js
db.eval(function(){

    db.primary_collection.find({},
        {  id: 1, parentid: 1, title: 1 }).forEach(function(doc){

        var newDoc = {};            

        Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key) {
            var newKey = ( key == "_id" ) ? key : "p$" + key;
            newDoc[newKey] = doc[key];
        });

        db.secondary_collection.insert(newDoc);

    });


})
```

Which uses [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) to execute the code **on** the server, which will be as fast as you will get.

But please **read** the documentation on this as you will be "locking" the database while this operation takes place. And of course you cannot do this across servers if that is your intent.